# Want to create Table in Salesforce Lightning which have Expand/Collapse option in Each row

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have created a page in Visualforce which is having Expand.Collapse button for each row. Now I want it same as in Lightning also.

Comment: Yes Shubham you can achieve this by calling another component from the row  .

Comment: Thanks Ajay. 
Like I have multiple  row and I have give a button Show Detail on Each row then How I will show the related detail of that particular row data. Is there any piece of code do you have ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this recently in a setup where I have a component per row and toggle what is visible using CSS via a boolean attribute:

```
<aura:component>

    <aura:attribute name="compact" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="slds-m-top--xx-small slds-m-bottom--xx-small">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-m-left_none" onclick="{! c.makeRowDetailed }">
                    <lightning:icon iconName="utility:chevronright" size="x-small" class="{! v.compact ? 'slds-show' : 'slds-hide' }" title="Show row detail" alternativeText="Show row detail"/>
                </button>
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-m-left_none" onclick="{! c.makeRowCompact }">
                    <lightning:icon iconName="utility:chevrondown" size="x-small" class="{! !v.compact ? 'slds-show' : 'slds-hide' }" title="Hide row detail" alternativeText="Hode row detail"/>
                </button>
            </div>
        </td>

        ... class="{! v.compact ? 'slds-show' : 'slds-hide' }" ...

    </tr>

</aura:component>
```

You will have to apply `class="{! v.compact ? 'slds-show' : 'slds-hide' }"` to the content you want to vary.

The controller methods just set the boolean attribute:

```
({
    makeRowCompact: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.compact", true);
    },

    makeRowDetailed: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.compact", false);
    },
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Check these links. Let me know if you face any difficulty. 
http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/create-collapsible-panel-component-in-lightning/

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_ui_collapse.htm

Answer (score 0):

You have to write whole custom logic for this in javascript to show and hide for this Pass a dynamic Id on button and provide this same id to the class of elemnet you need to show on button click. Now on click button event simply get the id of button then search for the same class and then you can toggle class.